# Помогите с php7 и GET запросом

Tags: php, get, php7

Всем привет, руки дошли до 7пхп и тут началось. 
Проблема с ГЕТ запросом , не хочет работать...

Пример на 5пхп и sql (РАБОТАЕТ)

```
if($_GET['cat']){$cat = $_GET['cat'];
// вытягиваем и сравниваем через гет запрос ссылку в ячейке
$sqlc = "SELECT * FROM cat WHERE url='$cat'";
$rowc = mysql_query($sqlc);
$crow = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowc);

$idcat = $crow['id']; // вытягиваем ID для дальнейшей работы
}
```

Пример на 7пхп и pdo (НЕ РАБОТАЕТ)

```
 if($_GET['cat']){$cat = $_GET['cat'];

    $sqlc = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM cat WHERE url='$cat'");
    while ($crow = $sqlc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))

$idcat = $crow['id']; 
}
```

в чем юмор я не знаю, кто в теме подскажите потму что перебрал сайт, а решить не могу

В штакесе

```
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]*)$ /file.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

Comment: А что именно то не работает? Какие ошибки или результаты видны? Что за народ пошёл, не умеет отлаживать программы, все полагается на "чутьё" ;) Чего стоит запустить с отладкой и ПОШАГОВО посмотреть значения переменных?

Comment: Для начала хотябы изучите технологии с которыми работаете, к примеру изучите подготовленные запросы, так же поработайте с дампом.

Comment: Автор, зачем вам PDO, если вы переменные прямо в запрос вставляете :) Почитайте http://phpfaq.ru/pdo

Answer (score 3):

Логика в заголовке примерно та же, что в известном [анекдоте](http://phpfaq.ru/humor/anecdotes#roach). Поэтому будем осваивать базовые принципы формальной логики.

Выводы всегда надо делать по прямым, а не косвенным последствиям. Чтобы проверить то или иное утверждение, необходимо проверять только его. То есть, условно говоря, проверять слух, а не способность бегать.

Допустим, нас интересует, работают ли GET запросы в РНР. Для этого логично будет проверить, заполняются ли GET переменные. То есть тупо узнать, есть ли у нас что-то в массиве $_GET. следующая строчка кода, помещенная в самом начале скрипта

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

ответит нам на этот животрепещущий вопрос современности.

Если, паче чаяния, с GET запросами окажется все в порядке, придется заняться таким увлекательным делом, как отладка, для начала включив вывод всех ошибок, поместив следующие строки также в самом начале скрипта

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```